# How do I highlight search queries using Vue+html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Here my search is working but I am a newbie and doesn't know how to use the npm...I am using HTML with VueJS to implement this and successsfully created the search filter but couldn't implement the highlight filter..Some leads are markjs.io that is used and some other custom vuejs filters but couldn't implement them.

```js
class Post {
  constructor(title, link, author, img, course, coursel, cours, coursl, cour, courl, cou, coul, co, col) {
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.author = author;
    this.img = img;
    this.course = course;
    this.coursel = coursel;
    this.cours = cours;
    this.coursl = coursl;
    this.cour = cour;
    this.courl = courl;
    this.cou = cou;
    this.coul = coul;
    this.co = co;
    this.col = col;
  }
}
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    search: "",
    postList: [
      new Post("abc", null, "xyz", "wqw", "qwe", "", " ", null, " ", null, " ", null, " ", null, );
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.postList.filter(post => {
        return post.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||
          post.author.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || 
          post.course.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || 
          post.cours.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || 
          post.cour.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || 
          post.cou.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) || 
          post.co.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the HTML code I am using

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search"
      onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
      onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-4 card" v-for="post in filteredList">
      <a v-bind:href="post.link" target="_blank">
        <img v-bind:src="post.img"/> 
        <div style="line-height:20%;">
          <br>
        </div>
        <font size="2">{{ post.author }}</font>
        <div class="brmedium"></div>
        <font size="5"><b><i><em>{{ post.title }}</em></i></b></font>
      <a v-bind:href="post.coursel" title="View Credential" target="_blank"><font size="3">{{ post.course }}</font></a>
      <a v-bind:href="post.coursl" title="View Credential" target="_blank"><font size="3">{{ post.cours }}</font></a>
      <a v-bind:href="post.courl" title="View Credential" target="_blank"><font size="3">{{ post.cour }}</font></a>
      <a v-bind:href="post.coul" title="View Credential" target="_blank"><font size="3">{{ post.cou }}</font></a>
      <a v-bind:href="post.col" title="View Credential" target="_blank"><font size="3">{{ post.co }}</font></a>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with npm? npm is a package manager.

Comment: I don't know yet how to use npm and add packages to code..my code has HTML,CSS and this JS files only..

Comment: your title says you don't want to use npm, your post talks about something that has nothing to do with npm, so: why mention npm?

Comment: generally devs don't use html with vuejs and use jsx (not sure abt that too) so I don't to attract answers on that front..

Comment: that still has nothing to do with npm, but is also not even true. plenty of folks use vue, plenty of other folks use react, but plenty more folks use "neither of those two". Just tag your question with the correct tags, and title and describe the problem to the degree necessary to let others help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="text" @input="input" />
    <p id="x">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit āmet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
      eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
      voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
      clita kasd gubergren, nò sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
      amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
      nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/*eslint-disable */
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      t: String(""),
      text: String(""),
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.t = document.querySelector("#x").innerText;
  },
  methods: {
    input() {
      document.querySelector("#x").innerHTML = this.t.replaceAll(
        this.text,
        `<span class='h'>${this.text}</span>`
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.h {
  background: red;
}
</style>
```

Simple highligh searching this might help you

Comment: Actually I have data to be displayed separately and not all at once in paragraph style so can I add parameters to search so that all of my data could be searched..like

<p id="y">lorem ipsum... </p> and then

replace each instance of "#x" with "#x,#y"  so that both of my text pieces when searched can be highlighted?

Comment: You can re-produced that code. So you need to add tag (more than #x) and manage them

Comment: yes so basically I have a course name and then some have sub courses as well and then author also..and this needs to be structured well for display..

Comment: Also please if you can convert the code into defined html,css and js files it would be more useful for me